# In how many non-isomorphic ways can the graph be labelled?

Tags: graph-theory

[image: In how many non-isomorphic ways can the following graph be labelled?]

In how many non-isomorphic ways can the graph above be labelled?

There are 5 ways to label the middle vertex, $\binom42=6$ ways of labelling the 2 vertices on the left and 2 ways to label the vertices on the right.
So in total there are 60 non-isomorphic ways.

But is this the right way to solve this question?

Comment: What do you mean by an isomorphism of the labeling?  Obviously all assignments of labels to these graphs give you isomorphic graphs...

Comment: I assume you mean labelling the vertices distinctly: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed five ways of labelling the middle vertex, but the graph has symmetries:

- swapping the left and right pairs of vertices
- within each of those pairs, swapping the individual vertices

These imply that the number of non-isomorphic ways to label the degree-2 vertices is the number of ways to split the four remaining labels into two groups: $\binom42/2=3$. Therefore there are only 15 non-isomorphic labellings.